# Inconsistent dependency on systemd package versions

Tags: apt, dependencies, 22.04, mint

This looks strange:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4)
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4)
 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
 libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 is to be installed
 systemd-coredump : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4)
 systemd-sysv : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4)
```

I could probably remove the i386 library, but why this mix between 3.6 and 3.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my arm64 environment, phased update of systemd was progressing to 70% and then has rolled back to 0%. I feel we have to wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look:

```
$ apt-cache policy libnss-systemd
libnss-systemd:
  Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3.6
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3.6 500 (phased 0%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Aha: `(phased 0%)`. You're seeing a package in the midst of Phased Updates, and that can affect dependencies, too.

When phasing completes, you won't see a discrepancy or "mix" anymore.